# How Spring finds the matched bean?

Tags: java, spring

I declared beans,such as `RedisTemplate<Long, Permission>`, `RedisTemplate<Long, Order>`, in RedisConfiguration.
The code show below,

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Order> orderRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Order> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    configure(redisTemplate, redisConnectionFactory);
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Permission> permissionRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Permission> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    configure(redisTemplate, redisConnectionFactory);
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

By default, The name of the declared name is the name of the declared method.
Now, I wrote a test code which declares a filed annotated @Autowired in TestController. 
The test code as follows:

```
@Autowired
RedisTemplate<String, Permission> permissionTemplate;
```

Then, I accessed to the TestController. It worked fine.
But, I have a question in the test. 
How Spring finds the Bean declared in RedisConfiguration and assigns to the permissionTemplate filed?
As we know, The generic type had been removed in Java compiled time, 
so it is impossible that Spring finds the right Bean by Generic Type.
The next possibility is that Spring finds the declared Bean by filedName. 
To approve my suggestion, I modified the filed in TestController, as follows.

```
@Autowired
RedisTemplate<String, Permission> orderTemplate;
```

Then, I requested the TestController. It also worked fine.  The test indicates that Spring uses the Generic Type to find matched Bean.

How Spring knows permissionTemplate's generic type ?

Comment: Yes there is type erasure, *BUT* type information is still preserved in method signature.  IIRC Spring relies on the getter/setter method signature to get know of the type param for properties and use it for auto-wiring.  So in your `TestController`, adding a corresponding getter should work.

Comment: Hi， thx for you comment. The previous question I posted was wrong and then  I modified my question. Could you take a moment to look my issue again?  really thank you.

Comment: Same answer for me: I believe you have getter/setter for the attribute, and Spring gets the generic type info from the getter/setter signature.  (btw, I guess it should be `RedisTemplate<String, Order> orderTemplate;` right?)

Comment: I didn't write getter/setter for the orderRedisTemplate and permissionRedistemplate. I just add annotation @Autowired on the both fileds.

Comment: apart from method signature, field itself also have generic type information saved.  Spring is using all these to find out the generic type information for its generics support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are type erasure for Java generics, but generic type information still exists in bytecode for a lot of scenario, like Field, return type and method parameters.  Spring use these information to determine the generic type information, and hence do the bean type matching.

Demonstration of generic info being available in runtime:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class Foo {
    private List<String> fooField;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        for (Field f : Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (f.getName().equals("fooField")) {
                System.out.println("Generic Types " + f.getGenericType());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should see the output:

```
Generic Types java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

Comment: thank you, I really need to study java basic knowledge again.

Comment: u r welcome. I won't consider it as "basic" knowledge though :p I personally forgot Field also have generic type info preserved in the first place :P